# How to add to your bash script help option "yourscript --help"

Tags: linux, bash

is there any possibility to add "help" to written by you bash script in Linux (Debian)? I mean specifically, by using command `yourscript --help` or `yourscript -h`

Comment: in some high level programming languages, some packages will come with a help formatter so that a help can be generated with the definitions of the options. sadly, not quite capable for bash only.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be harder than this.

```
case $1 in
 -[h?] | --help)
    cat <<-____HALP
        Usage: ${0##*/} [ --help ]
        Outputs a friendly help message if you can figure out how.
____HALP
        exit 0;;
esac
```

If you use `getopts` for option processing, use that to identify the option; but the action is going to look more or less similar (and IMNSHO `getopts` doesn't really offer anything over a simple `while ... shift` loop).

Answer (score 1):

[`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)

```
#!/bin/bash

args=$(getopt -n "$(basename "$0")" -o h --longoptions help -- "$@") || exit 1
eval set -- "$args"

while :; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help) echo offer help here ; exit ;;
        --) shift; break ;;
        *) echo "error: $1"; exit 1;;
    esac
done

echo "hello world, $*"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Over time I have come to prefer separate `usage` and `help` functions. The `help` is provided in response to a request for either `--help` or `-h` and it provides extended help/option information in a `heredoc` format. The `usage` function is provided in response to an invalid input. It is short and provides a quick reminder of what the script needs. Both functions take a string as the first argument that allows you to pass an error message to be displayed along with the `help` or `usage`. Both also allow you to pass an `exit code` as the second argument.

The following is an example I pulled from an existing script. You can ignore the contents, but it was left by way of example:

```
function help {
  local ecode=${2:-0}

  [[ -n $1 ]] && printf "\n $1\n" >&2

cat >&2 << helpMessage

  Usage: ${0##*/} <ofile> <file.c> [ <cflags> ... --log [ \$(<./bldflags)]]

    ${0##*/} calls 'gcc -Wall -o <ofile> <file.c> <cflags> <\$(<./bldflags)>'
    If the file './bldflags' exists in the present directory, its contents are
    read into the script as additional flags to pass to gcc. It is intended to
    provide a simple way of specifying additional libraries common to the source
    files to be built. (e.g. -lssl -lcrypto).

    If the -log option is given, then the compile string and compiler ouput are
    written to a long file in ./log/<ofile>_gcc.log

  Options:

    -h  |  --help  program help (this file)
    -l  |  --log   write compile string and compiler ouput to ./log/<ofile>_gcc.log

helpMessage

  exit $ecode
}

function usage {
  local ecode=${2:-0}

  [[ -n $1 ]] && printf "\n $1\n" >&2

  printf "\n  Usage: %s <ofile> <file.c> [ <cflags> ... --log [ \$(<./bldflags)]]\n\n" "${0##*/}"

  exit $ecode
}
```

I generally test for `help` when looking at all arguments, e.g.:

```
## test for help and log flags and parse remaining args as cflags
for i in $*; do
    test "$i" == "-h" || test "$i" == "--help" && help
    ...
done
```

Usage is provided in response to an invalid input, e.g.:

```
[ -f "$1" ] || usage "error: first argument is not a file." 1
```

They come in handy and I've preferred this approach to `getopts`.